# How to know what elements are in current mouse position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need know what elements are in current mouse position and I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you need to find out the element over the mouse is currently on. If this is correct you can use

```
document.elementFromPoint ( x, y );
```

[document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.elementFromPoint)

> Returns the element from the document
>   whose elementFromPoint method is being
>   called which is the topmost element
>   which lies under the given point.  The
>   point is specified via coordinates, in
>   CSS pixels, relative to the
>   upper-left-most point in the window or
>   frame containing the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(this).mousemove(function(e){
      var elem = document.elementFromPoint ( e.pageX , e.pageY );
    alert ( elem.id );
   }); 
})
```