# Jquery on hover (when there is an element above the element we're hovering)

Tags: jquery, hover

So there are two elements on top of eachother. How do i call a function as soon as the element (under the one on top) is hovered?

Thanks alot, I really need this to work :s

Comment: Are they simply on top of one another because of the CSS or is contained in the other in the DOM?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1471047/901048 -- you could always try rapidly hiding the topmost element, detecting what's right under it, and then showing that topmost element again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) property:

> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse events, the value none instructs the mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.

```
#top {
   pointer-events: none;
}

$('#underneath').hover(function(){
     ....  
})
```

Comment: @ShivanRaptor No, unfortunately, even IE9 doesn't support the property.