# Jquery Stop stacked element from hovering out

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'v been stuck on this for ages.

```
$(".poster-wrapper.tint").hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".controls").slideDown('fast');
}, function (e) {
    //Here is where I need if statement. Only slide up if the poster **and** the controls class is not being hovered on
    $(this).siblings(".controls").slideUp('fast');
});
```

`.controls` is ontop of the `.poster-wrapper`, so when I hover over poster wrapper it shows the controls class correctly, but when I hover over controls class they slide away again obviously because the poster is no longer being hovered on. How do I stop this unwanted behavior?

I'v looked at other threads on here but still can't work it out for multiple elements.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9dzfys87/

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Jaydo Done. If you hover in and out of black square, the slide down works fine. If you hover over blue square in middle it tries to go back up.

I want it to just stay shown even when on blue square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on another StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556202/jquery-on-hover-when-there-is-an-element-above-the-element-were-hovering).

Add `pointer-events: none;` to your `.controls` class.

```
.controls{
  pointer-events: none;
  /* other properties */
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dzfys87/7/).

**-- Update to work with click events --**

Place one div inside the other

```
 <div class="poster-wrapper tint">
      <div class="controls"></div>
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dzfys87/8/)

Comment: This disable all click() events too. I don't want that.

Comment: Yes it does unfortunately. If you don't mind putting `.controls` inside `.poster-wrapper` it will work. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9dzfys87/8/)

Comment: Good enough, never thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson Could you please accept my answer if I solved your problem? Cheers.