# Is there a way to find the div name out from from location(x,y cords)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is fairly easy to find the location of a div, when you know the div name. But is there an easy way to get the div id when all I know is the X/Y cords of the screen?

There will be no overlapping divs within a range of divs named '#Items1' to '#Items50' on a board (another div) called #HarbourRadar. Each div #Items can have more than one stacked image in it.

Anyway any hint to find the div out from a location would be greatly appreciated.

The following code (taken from the answer below on this side) gets the id of the div #HarbourRadar, that is partially right since the div #marker is layered ontop on that one, but does not return the div #marker that is selected - ie one with a higher Z-index.

```
var pos = $("#marker").position();
alert(document.elementFromPoint(pos.left, pos.top).id);
```

Comment: Why do you want to find it by coordinates? How do you get the coordinates?

Comment: Not real sure if this would work, but have you tried adding a click handler on the body tag and then checking the 'target' property to see if it gives you the original source?

Comment: @Lars, well I am working on a gridbased board, so I know the X,Y cordinates quite well.  ie getting the location from a marker would be like this.

    var pos = $("#marker").position();
    alert('X cord:' + pos.posX);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the DOM node that is at a given (X,Y) position? (Hit test)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569775/how-do-i-find-the-dom-node-that-is-at-a-given-x-y-position-hit-test) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/48999/218196 and possible also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1471047/218196.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yeah, it is possible using the `document.elementFromPoint` method.
This is how it is documented by [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536417%28VS.85%29.aspx).
Here is [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint).
The function is almost fully compatible, as you can see in [this browser comparison](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#documentview).

Here is some sample code from MDN docs:

```js
function changeColor(newColor) {
  elem = document.elementFromPoint(2, 2);
  elem.style.color = newColor;
}
```

```html
<p id="para1">Some text here</p>
<button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>
```

Comment: Great answer, I'd never heard of this before :)

Comment: I was wondering too, when I was it first time. But I still doubt about compatibility of this thing.

Comment: Also take a look here http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/

Comment: @TomášZato me too, that's why I checked: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html. It has support in everything except old WinSafari and old Opera.

Comment: Also here too, http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/06/more_ie9_goodne.html `As a result elementFromPoint() is now truly usable.`

Comment: That is really great and can see it is supported by mobile devices as well. But how do I from there get the ID? ie var pos = $("#marker").position(); alert(document.elementFromPoint(pos.left, pos.top)); returns with "[object HTMLDivElement]"

Comment: This is because the function returns [Html Element Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp). One of its properties is `id`. So do `document.elementFromPoint(pos.left, pos.top).id`. But in most cases it is better to use element itself.

Comment: Hi Tomas, yes I found out. But is there a way to literate through all divs at a given location? Could see that document.elementFromPoint(pos.left, pos.top).id actually returns the div ##HarbourRadar, that got the lovest z-index(I forgot that the map was nested in a div too) and not the div with the higest z-index as I would have expected.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this existing StackOverflow conversation you may find this helps:

[Determine which element the mouse pointer is on top of in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813051/determine-which-element-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-top-of-in-javascript)

This is using a javascript function `document.elementFromPoint` and has a great demo that shows a working example.

The jsFiddle URL is: http://jsfiddle.net/MPTTp/

Code from the fiddle:

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY,
        elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    alert(elementMouseIsOver);
});
```